# graphics all change to same color when map zooms in or out

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, map-drawing

As the title states, I have a working "draw tool" where you can draw on the map using polygons, simple marker symbols, lines, and text. Whenever you draw any of these symbols on the map using different colors and you zoom in or out all of the symbols will change to the same color.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you asking why they all change to the same color, or how to get them to change to the same color?

Comment: sorry, Im asking why they do I cannot understand it for the life of me I've been going through this for awhile. I can draw any shape fine any colour any size but when i zoom out or pan to the left and then back to where you can see the graphic they all set to the last colour used

Comment: Please post your code. My guess is that you're re-using the same symbol object for all graphics. Once the map re-draws graphics (after you pan or zoom) all get drawn using the last symbol properties your app set since all graphics reference the same symbol.

Comment: i cant the code is way too long for this box, so i figure just reset the symbol after I draw it. I would create the symbol right when I was actually going to draw it but I need it created globally to set attributes to it throughout the code

Comment: if it helps any to put some context behind what I am doing, in the esri flex api there is a draw tool foudn here http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=91a0014160fc4a9caadc2c7fd7089c1b that I have recreated in javascript. it all functions correctly only when i pan or zoom does it redraw all graphics incorrectly

Comment: Is there a explicit renderer set on the featureLayer? Or is it taking the default one from the layer?